Gradle issue syncing for libgdx
so, when trying to Sync gradle for the project, i get the following errors:

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/Lists
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists
Unable to load class 'org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists'
org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.`
I have looked online and couldn't find any fixes, so any help would be great.
here's my build.gradle file if that helps.
buildscript {
    

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.docstr:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.1.29'
        classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.20'
        

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "tankgame"
        gdxVersion = '1.12.1'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.20'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.4'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'
        gdxControllersVersion = '2.2.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxControllersVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxControllersVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-ios:$gdxControllersVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"
    apply plugin: "org.gretty"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:2.0.2:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-core:$gdxControllersVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-gwt:$gdxControllersVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-gwt:$gdxControllersVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion:sources"
        
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-core:$gdxControllersVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        
    }
}

i have tried other fixes like searching the error, and i couldn't find anything conclusive.
